# Fork again a original repo

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I forked a repository and cloned it in my local environment, I did some changes in master and create a pull request to merge my changes with the original repo.

But, I have to correct a new bug and I don't want to correct this bug in master of my forked repo, I want to "fork again" in another branch and call it "bugXXX" and create another pull request just with changes to fix this specific bug.

So, how can I fork again in another branch the original repo and fix the bug and create another pull request ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, git command line. (github is the repo)

Answer (score 0):

There is some lack of detail in your question, but I think this is what you want to do.

You don't have to "fork again". Just create a new local branch, say `fix-bugXXX`:

```
git checkout -b fix-bugXXX
```

Fix the bug on this branch, add your changes and commit them locally:

```
git add file1 file2
git commit -m "Fix bugXXX"
```

After that, push this new branch to your **own** `GitHub` repository. This will create the new branch `fix-bugXXX` on your GitHub repo as well. Assuming that you left things named by default, the command is:

```
git push origin fix-bugXXX
```

In the end, just go to GitHub and create a new pull request from your `fix-bugXXX` branch to one of the original repo's branches.

Comment: thanks,just to confirm this new branch is a exactly a copy of the original forked repo ?

Comment: When you do a `git checkout -b fix-bugXXX`, you create and move on a new branch that is an exact copy of the branch you were when you ran this command (probably `master`). If this branch is an *exact copy* of the original forked repo, then yes.

Comment: If you've modified your local `master` branch, you can still create the new branch from a previous commit (presumably one that's already in the remote master). To do this, use `git branch fix-bugXXX <sha-of-the-commit>`.